# Multiplier at the end of join() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

I'm new to Javascript and was completing a training excerise. The problem is to return the highest outcome of the number of digits given.

Example: "678" should return 876.

**Here's the code I wrote:**

```
function max(n){  let r  = (""+n).split("")
  r.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
  let result = r.join("")
return result;
}
```

I consoled out `result` to see if it did what I needed and would get `'876'` which I assumed was the correct but, would fail the test cases with response `expected '876' to equal 876`

I searched around and ending up finding a similar solution that added `*1` at the end of `join()` like so:

```
let result = r.join("")*1
```

I'm having trouble understanding why I'd need that for it to be correct - Can someone help me understand why that would be necessary?

Comment: Because Strings are not Numbers. Sounds like the test wanted the output in the form of a Number. So the String `"876"`, is coerced into a Number when multiplied by the Number `1`.

Comment: other options `+r.join()` and `Number(r.join())` - note the delimeter argument of `join(delimiter)` can be omitted if it's empty `""` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @RandyCasburn @ Kinglish - Thanks for the clarity I understand now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r.join("")*1` coerces the result to a number instead of returning a string. It appears that the output of the function is being compared using strict equality to the expected result, which is also a number. Other methods to do this include using the unary plus operator (i.e., `+r.join("")`), the `Number` function, and `parseInt`.